# It is possible to delete cookies in wp7 webbrowser control?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing an application for windows phone 7. I use WebBrowser control and i want to delete cookies collected during the user navigation. I tried the code below but it doesn't work(currentTab.browser is of type WebBrowser).

```
      foreach (Cookie c in currentTab.browser.GetCookies())
        {
            c.Discard = true;
            c.Expired = true;
            c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D);
        }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As far as Windows Phone 8 concerned you can use `ClearCookiesAsync();` method to clear the cookies.